# What is the score that plays during the Cochinay assault in the mission "And the Truth Will Set You Free" in Red Dead Redemption?

Tags: red-dead-redemption, game-music-identification

What is that epic music that plays when you fight your way through to Dutch Van Der Linde's fort in Cochinay?

Starts here at 7:36:

What is the name of this score? I've scoured Youtube, but it only could only find the Cochinay theme...

It seems to sound like "[The Outlaw's Return](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=4k4i0Tjo7J4#t=200s)"

Comment: VERY CLOSE TO THE LAST MINUTE OF THE http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4k4i0Tjo7J4&playnext=1&list=PL880D572DF1EA418B&feature=results_main

Answer (score 1):

First off, you might want to edit the question to remove the spoiler. (re Dutchman Final mission)

The Official Red Dead Redemption soundtrack is available via [iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/theme-from-red-dead-redemption/id371357204?i=371357567&ign-mpt=uo=6)

or as a physical CD from Rockstar directly.

I'm thinking that the music that you are looking for is actually from the Score not on the OST though. I don't think that music is officially available.